# MySQL Generating unique primary key using varchar with 65 digits

Tags: mysql, casting, varchar

I understood that in MySQL we can cast varchar to Decimal(65,0). So to create a primary key value while inserting record I'm using below query.

```
INSERT INTO users (USERID, UNIQUECODE) VALUES(
(SELECT (COALESCE(MAX(CAST(USERID AS DECIMAL(65, 0))), 1) + 1) AS NEXTID FROM (SELECT * FROM users) AS myusers)
, 'NEW 1')
```

This is working as I expected. Now I can have a primary key have of maximum 65 digits. 
***Can anyone please tell me, is there any problem using this query ?*** 
Or is there any better way ?

***My requirement is to have a primary key field with more than 50 digits. The limitation of BIGINT(20) is the problem I can't use it here.***
*If there was something like BIGINT(50) then I would have used this with auto increment.* Hope I'm clear enough.

Thank You :-)

Comment: Just as a side note, maybe you could add why you need such a massive number as a primary key.  I think you would run out of storage space long before your auto increment column gets anywhere near 65 digits.

Comment: Why so many digits? BIGINT is already stupid huge in that you could assign individual numbers to every single insect on the planet. Generally if you need larger numbers you're generating random keys, in which case a base-64 or hex-encoded `VARCHAR` value is best. To put it in perspective you can generate 5.8 *billion* keys *per second* for *a hundred years* and not run out of BIGINT range.

Comment: Thanks for replying. 
There is no too much data stored in the database. Only few string to save only 1 layout of an android app. In app, each user can have many accounts. This is the only reason.

Comment: Come on, use an `INT` if this data is only used locally. This 65 digit number for a handful of things is absurd. If you need guaranteed unique numbers to avoid collisions, use a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) and store it as a `VARCHAR`.